# How to run test cases from a Testsuite inside a Testplan through command line

Tags: microsoft-test-manager, tcm

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TCM.exe" run /create "/title:Overnight Build Run" /planid:8 /collection:http://hahaha:8080/tfs/DevelopmentCollection /teamproject:SQL"/querytext:SELECT * FROM TestSuite WHERE Planid='8'" "/settingsname:SoakTest" /owner:test\test /builddir:\\wxxx\Builds\SQL\Live "/testenvironment:Soak" /include
```

It runs all Tests in Test Plan I only want to Run Tests from Test Suites inside this Test Plan, what should be the query?

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how to find out Test Suite ID No

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

TCM suites  /list  /planid:8 /collection:your peoject TFS URL /teamproject:Project Name
```

Answer (score 4):

You can run Test Cases which belong to a particular Test Suite using parameter /suiteid calling tcm.exe:

```
TCM.exe run /create /title:<Title> /planid:<PlanId> /suiteid:<SuiteId> /collection:http://hahaha:8080/tfs/DevelopmentCollection /teamproject:SQL /settingsname:SoakTest /owner:test\test /builddir:\\wxxx\Builds\SQL\Live /testenvironment:Soak /include
```

Use

```
tcm.exe suites /list /planid:<your plan id> /collection:<CollectionURL> /teamproject:<Team Project name>
```

to list all Test Suites belonging to the particular Test Plan.

Comment: Elena, your example showed me how to make my collection url. Many Thanks! There are lots of examples that tell you to you use collection url but yours explains how...